# Gromov norm and free $Z_2$-space

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-actions

The Gromov norm of a compact oriented n-manifold is a norm on the homology (with real coefficients) given by minimizing the sum of the absolute values of the coefficients over all singular chains representing a cycle. The Gromov norm of the manifold is the Gromov norm of the fundamental class. It is known, the following class of manifold has a non-zero Gromov norm:

$(1)$ Oriented closed connected Riemannian manifolds of negative sectional curvature.

$(2)$ Oriented closed connected hyperbolic manifolds.

$\textbf{Q})$ I am interested in knowing a list of examples of orientable manifolds with non-zero Gromov norm that admit a free $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action.

As one example, we can consider the genus $g>1$ torus $T_g$. Since $T_g$ is a hyperbolic manifold, its Gromov norm is non-zero by (2). Moreover, If we assume
this is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in a standard way, with the “center” of the torus at the origin, then the antipodal map $x\to -x$ define a free $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action on it.

Comment: Of the examples you cite of manifolds with non-zero Gromov norm, do you know of any explicit calculations?

Comment: Indeed, the Gromov norm of $T_g$ is $2|\chi(T_g)|$. Please see  http://math.uchicago.edu/~cbutler/GromovNorm.pdf , page 3, for the calculation.

Comment: (Q) is essentially equivalent to asking for a list of manifolds with $H^1(M;\Bbb Z/2) \neq 0$ and non-zero Gromov norm. I do not see why this should be attainable. Certainly a great many hyperbolic manifolds have this property.